# SQL Server - copy and modify a year's data

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

In need of a guide here.
I have a set of records for the year 2019, the entire 365 days, that I need to make some updates with. The things that I need to do are:

1. Update a column from another column in the table. So the staffing_date column = date.
2. Make a copy of the records into the same table.
3. Update a column with either "Day" or "Night". 1 day would have two records - one for "day" and one for "night"
4. Update a column based on the values from other columns, i.e. if it is"day" and "weekday" then the leave_num = 38. If it's "night" and weekend" then the leave num = 33.

Examples of data:

```
Staffing_date   day_night caldendar_year    date     weekend_ind  month leave_num   
NULL            NULL         2019        2019-01-01   WEEKDAY      1     NULL  
NULL            NULL         2019        2019-01-02   WEEKDAY      1     NULL
NULL            NULL         2019        2019-01-12   WEEKEND      1     NULL
```

Staffing_date needs to be updated with the date in the same row. I think I can figure this part out, but for the rest, I am not sure what will be the best way to go about it?

For #3, I'm trying to use the CROSS APPLY as suggested below, but I don't think I'm using it right.

```
insert into mytable (day_night)
select days
from mytable
CROSS APPLY (
values('day'), ('night')) v(days)
where calendar_year = '2019'
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far to complete this yourself? As for your statements: *"1. Update a column from another column in the table."* This is far too vague. Update the column to what, based on what? *"2. Make a copy of the records."* To where? Another Table, a File, a USB device, paper? *"Update a column with either "Day" or "Night""* Based on what logic? Days have both day and night so what makes one day "night" and another "day". *"4.Update a column based on the values from other columns, i.e. if it is"day" 
and "weekday" then the leave_num = 38." Maybe the only request we can help with

Comment: Sorry. Added more info.

Comment: And what bout your attempts and point number 2?#

Comment: #2 is in progress at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I'll await your attempts and explanation then, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. #1 and #2 are done - selecting for the 2019 records and inserting them back into the same table. Now onto #3... Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

If I follow the exact order that you are mentioned, it would be:

1. Update a column from another column in the table.
   Update MyTable
   SET MyCol1 = Mycol2
2. Make a copy of the records.
   Inside the same table? O you only need a backup of this table (SELECT INTO ..), if you want to insert into the same table you should provide us the structure and PK-NC and every restriction associated.

3.Update a column with either "Day" or "Night"
What criteria you will use for replace Day or Night.

4.Update a column based on the values from other columns, i.e. if it is"day" 
and "weekday" then the leave_num = 38.

```
Update MyTable  set
column1 = (case when condition<(column2='Day" And column3="weekday)> then leave_num=38 else column1 end) .....
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP's requests are far too vague, and you even ask for elaboration yourself in your answer.

Comment: So after making a copy of the records inside the same table, there will be a total of 730 records for the year, and each day would have two records - one for "day" and one for "night".

Comment: According your comment, you should do an INSERT INTO YourTable SELECT .. FROM YourTable, it should include a filter related to the year and change the value of Day by Night

Answer (score 1):

If you're left with just 3 and 4, then you can easily get every value in your table with the value `day` and `night` by using `APPLY` and `VALUES`

```
FROM YourTable YT
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Day'),('Night')) V(Day_Night)
```

Finally, to get your 33/38 logic, this might work depending on your language:

```
CASE WHEN V.Day_Night = 'Day' AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY,YT.[date]) IN ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday') THEN 38 
     WHEN V.Day_Night = 'Night' AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY,YT.[date]) IN ('Saturday','Sunday') THEN 38
END
```

Note that the above does not have logic for Night weekdays, and day time at the weekend, and so would return the value `NULL`.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the day/night part a bit? Still not quite getting it...

Comment: What part is it you're struggling with @KenshinH the `CROSS APPLY` or the `VALUES`? I *assumed* that SQL was basically self explanatory.

Comment: The CROSS APPLY section.

Comment: [FROM (Transact-SQL) - Using APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply) @KenshinH. Effectively what I'm doing there is the same as a `CROSS JOIN`, but you can't use `CROSS JOIN` on the `VALUES` operator; hence the use of `APPLY` instead.

Comment: Still stuck at #3... @.@. I've added what I tried with in my question above, but obviously, it's not working. A bit more help, please?

Comment: Why are you inserting from MyTable into MyTable, and why only the column `days`? That`CROSS APPLY` needs to be part of your initial `INSERT`. You can't use an`INSERT` on its own to to do an upsert. Your table shouldn't be populated yet.

Comment: So, in very simple terms `INSERT INTO YourTable SELECT {columns} FROM YourSourceTable YTD CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Day'),('Night')) v(d);` (assumes `YourTable` is empty.)